If every power-bounded linear operator $T$ on the Banach space $X$ is mean ergodic, then the space $X$ is reflexive
Let $X$ be a (real or complex) Banach space (complete normed space).
If every power-bounded linear operator $T$ on the Banach space $X$ is mean ergodic, then the space $X$ is reflexive.
How to prove it?

See this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123601938066

@EvangelopoulosFoivos without schauder basis
